# Elasticsearch: use command curl -XPUT over several indexes begining with the same word

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

I want to run the following script over several indexes called `index1-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}`:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/index1* -d '
{
    "mappings" : {
      "index1" : {
        "properties" : {
            "location": {
                "type": "geo_point"
               }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

But the previous script doesn't work to due `'*'`.

Do you know how to solve that?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to put the same mapping to all the indexs??

if so, you can create a template. and put the index1* in it, so it will aply to all indexes starting with index1.

```
    curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/_template/template_name -d '
{
  "template": "index1*",
  "settings": {
    ....
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "name_mapping" : {
      "properties" : {
        "geometry" : {
          "type":"geo_shape",
          "tree":"quadtree",
          "precision":"1m"
        },
        ...
```

Comment: Good point, just note that this will not modify existing indices, but will only apply to future ones. To modify existing indices, use the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `_mapping` endpoint instead since the indices `index1*` already exist:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/index1*/_mapping/index1 -d '{
    "properties" : {
        "location": {
            "type": "geo_point"
        }
    }
}'
```